# Want to update columns based on two id's which have two percentages for them

Tags: sql-server

This is my stored procedure. Here i am get two id values with two percentages. i want to update the column amount in acc_cashbook based on the id column which have percentage to that id. but here it is updating only based on one id. i want to update based on two id's to their particular column. please help me.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[refdocedit]
(@RefDocID int, 
@LabNo int)
as
begin

declare @U_labNo int
declare @TestOrPkg int
declare @ID int
declare @StdAmt int
declare @Percentage decimal
declare @NameOfParty varchar(50)
declare @Voucher_NameOfParty varchar(50)
declare @Amount decimal

select @U_labNo=U_labNo from LabRegDetail where LabNo=@LabNo

select @TestOrPkg=TestOrPkg,@ID=ID,@StdAmt=StdAmt from LabPatientTestDetails where U_labNo=@U_labNo

select @Percentage=Percentage from RefDocLabCommission where RefDocID=@RefDocID and ID=@ID

update LabRegDetail set RefDocId=@RefDocID where LabNo=@LabNo



select NameOfParty,Voucher_NameOfParty,Amount from Acc_CashBook  where LabNo=@LabNo and ID=@ID
and Ns_Or_PHM=@TestOrPkg 



set @Amount=(select distinct (@Percentage/100)*@StdAmt from RefDocLabCommission rdlc,LabRegDetail lrd,LabTestMaster ltm,LabPatientTestDetails lptd,Acc_CashBook acc
where lrd.LabNo=acc.LabNo and lptd.U_labNo=lrd.U_labNo and lrd.RefDocId=rdlc.RefDocID and rdlc.ID=ltm.TestID  
and rdlc.ID=acc.ID and lrd.LabNo=@LabNo and acc.ID=@ID)

set @NameOfParty=(select  RefFirstName+''+RefMiddleName+''+RefLastName from RefDocMaster where  RefDocID=@RefDocID)


update Acc_CashBook set NameOfParty=@NameOfParty,Voucher_NameOfParty=@NameOfParty
 where LabNo=@LabNo and Voucher_PartyType=2
--and Ns_Or_PHM=@TestOrPkg and ID=@ID


update Acc_CashBook set Amount=@Amount where Voucher_PartyType=2 and LabNo=@LabNo 


update Acc_BankBook set NameOfParty=@NameOfParty,Voucher_NameOfParty=@NameOfParty
 where LabNo=@LabNo and Voucher_PartyType=2
--and Ns_Or_PHM=@TestOrPkg and ID=@ID


update Acc_BankBook set Amount=@Amount where Voucher_PartyType=2 and LabNo=@LabNo 



end
```

Comment: what you want to edit, what are these two ids??.... please be clear

Comment: Don't be afraid to use whitespace when writing SQL. It'll make your code more more legible to not only yourself but others that have to read it and it doesn't increase the performance of your query.

Comment: Personally I prefer the compact view, however it’s using old style joins which make it much harder to understand. I’d start there.

Comment: hai ravi,  I want to update the amount in acc_Cashbook. i have two id's 1 & 813. For 1 amount is 100 and 813 is 50. It is getting from the above query in procedure (set @Amount). Here based on that id that amount should update but for all records amount 50 is updating which is id 813. But i want to update indivual amounts based on thier id.

Comment: If there is three id's and three different amounts for the id's it should update based on that id.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is you are thinking procedurally - how you would do this in simple code, instead of set based. I have re-coded it as best I can based on my assumptions about the schemas. Have a look at this. Its now down to just a couple of set-based updates.

Also assumed the select query is still required, and that it might return multiple rows from the joins. If not, remove the distinct, or remove the query completely.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[refdocedit]
(@RefDocID int, 
@LabNo int)
as
begin

declare @NameOfParty varchar(50)

update LabRegDetail set RefDocId=@RefDocID where LabNo=@LabNo

select @NameOfParty= RefFirstName+''+RefMiddleName+''+RefLastName from RefDocMaster where  RefDocID=@RefDocID

select distinct acc.NameOfParty,acc.Voucher_NameOfParty,acc.Amount 
from LabRegDetail lrd
join LabPatientTestDetails lptd on lptd.U_labNo=lrd.U_labNo 
join Acc_CashBook acc on acc.ID=lptd.ID and acc.Ns_Or_PHM=lptd.TestOrPkg
where lrd.LabNo=@LabNo 

update acc set NameOfParty=@NameofParty, Voucher_NameOfParty=@NameOfParty,
    Amount=(rdlc.Percentage/100)*lptd.StdAmt
from LabRegDetail lrd
join LabPatientTestDetails lptd on lptd.U_labNo=lrd.U_labNo 
join Acc_CashBook acc on acc.ID=lptd.ID and acc.Voucher_PartyType=2
join LabRegDetail lrd on lrd.LabNo=acc.LabNo
join RefDocLabCommission rdlc on lrd.RefDocId=rdlc.RefDocID and rdlc.ID=acc.ID
where lrd.LabNo=@LabNo 

update bb set NameOfParty=@NameOfParty,Voucher_NameOfParty=@NameOfParty,
    Amount=(rdlc.Percentage/100)*lptd.StdAmt
from LabRegDetail lrd
join LabPatientTestDetails lptd on lptd.U_labNo=lrd.U_labNo 
join Acc_CashBook acc on acc.ID=lptd.ID and acc.Voucher_PartyType=2
join LabRegDetail lrd on lrd.LabNo=acc.LabNo
join RefDocLabCommission rdlc on lrd.RefDocId=rdlc.RefDocID and rdlc.ID=acc.ID
join Acc_BankBook b on bb.LabNo=lrd.LabNo and bb.Voucher_PartyType=2
where lrd.LabNo=@LabNo 

end
```